# itunes connect bundle id not available

Tags: ios, deployment, app-store-connect, bundle

I've created an app using Unity. Before uploading the archive, I'd tried to add a new app record in Itunes Connect, but it says that the bundle ID is already in use, even if there's not a single app with that bundle ID. The ID is the same of my project configuration. Why it says that it's in use?
The App Id and provisioning profile was generated by XCode using "fix issue", since doing it manually was creating issues with the project generated by Unity. There is no alert within the XCode project configuration, so I guess it's okay there, but still I can't upload it to the store...

Comment: It probably means that someone else is using that bundle ID. You need to choose another. Be sure your bundle ID is something like "com.mydomain.myapp". This avoids any problems.

Comment: yes, my app id already follows the pattern com.mydomain.myapp, that's why i don't think it is already in use, since it's really improbable. How can i check it?

Comment: You already did check it. iTunes Connect said it is in use so someone else is already using it.

Comment: So i should change the bundle id on the itunes connect and the project, right? i'll try

Comment: Done, it worked, even if it's really strange that it was in use since it was a really peculiar name... I didn't tried it because the last time it gave similar errors, but it was a different messy situation (deploying on ios is pretty difficult). Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changed the bundle id on both the project and online and it worked, actually I thought it was pretty strange the it was already used since it wasn't a usual name. Just run in a little issue with bundle id not related to the provisioning profile, but XCode fixed it without any problem.